# docker-compose pdo-mysql driver not found

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I am trying to Dockerize my project (PHP MYSQL and PDO). Even though I added the scripts to install the extensions to my Dockerfile and every time I build it is installing them I am still getting: "Could not find driver". I checked in the `phpinfo()` and the driver is not there. I deleted all images and containers, built from scratch. Same result. Any ideas? In my docker file I have the following:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql 
EXPOSE 80
```

and my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php74
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8008:80
  db:
     container_name: mysql8
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     image: mysql:latest
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_DATABASE: realDE
       MYSQL_USER: khaldoun
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
     ports:
       - 6033:3306
```

Comment: You say you've tried most solutions but there are a dozen duplicates for your question. Have you tried them all?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the answer to the duplicate you sent is exactly the same as my code. And yes i have gone through most of the ones i could find to no avail.

Comment: I just ran your code and the PDO extension was installed. I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: This is what is confusing me @JayBlanchard. In theory everything is right. I did fresh builds and everything

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right PHP info page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the test I performed, I did the following:

Dockerfile -

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY $PWD/index.php /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

# start Apache2 on image start
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl","-DFOREGROUND"]
```

index.php

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

run command (I named the image pdo-test):

```
docker run --name=pdo-test -p 8080:80  -d pdo-test
```

Once the container was started I navigated to HTTP://localhost:8080/index.php and saw the PDO driver is loaded:

[image]

Please note the only difference between my Dockerfile and yours is that I copied a PHP page into `/var/www/html` and added a command that would start Apache when the container is run.

Things you should check:

- is the volume you're mounting correct `./php:/var/www/html`
- since you have no command to execute Apache, confirm it is starting properly in the container. I tested both ways and it started each time, but you should bash into the container and make sure Apache is running as you expect.

**EDIT** I copied one of the php.ini files from the container

```
docker cp pdo-test:usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production php.ini
```

and uncommented the PDO drivers:

```
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
```

Then I rebuilt the container, copying in the updated php.ini file:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY $PWD/index.php /var/www/html
COPY $PWD/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

EXPOSE 80

# start Apache2 on image start
# CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl","-DFOREGROUND"]
```

I can now see the php.ini file in `phpinfo()`

[image]

Comment: I bashed into the container. Apache is there. However i noticed in phpinfo that the loaded config file is (none)

Comment: So it doesn't have a php.ini file?

Comment: No it only has php.ini-development and php.ini-production

Comment: And if you do ```php -m``` pdo_mysql is there

Comment: I just double-checked and there is no active php.ini, so what you might want to do is copy  one of those .ini files locally, modify it and then copy it into the right location when building the iamge.

Comment: i did that and it still didnt recognize it

Comment: @KhaldounNd we have arrived at the point where I would have to be looking over your shoulder to try to see the issues.

Comment: Just to double-check: did you build a new image after you made the changes to the Dockerfile?